# .substring() while dealing with multibyte characters in Java on Unix/Linux

Tags: java, encoding, decoding, multibyte

I have an encoded string (creation of which i have no information about and possibly cannot alter) which has 8 random characters at the beginning (before encoding and after decoding). And then valid data starts. Decoded string: `String plainText = @#$%^&@#valid_data`

Now when I do a `plainText.substring(8)` i get **valid_data**. Sometimes though, the random characters are multibyte, like **普%^&@#valid_data** where 普 has 3 characters. doing a `plainText.substring(8)` on this returns **lid_data** . 普 is counted as 1, and so the 8 characters extend upto **va**.

What i want is, for my code to count 普 as 3 and hence remove only 普%^&@# from the String `plainText`.

My php counterpart easily achieved this by making the string function multibyte-unsafe. i.e, using `substr()` instead of `mb_substr()`.

Is this possible in Java? Or the only way to ensure there is no loss of valid data is to make sure that multibyte characters do not get encrypted at all?

EDIT: I should probably add this- This works as i expect in my local windows environment but not on the Staging unix environment.

Comment: Have you tried with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointCount%28int,%20int%29 of String?

Comment: You need to get more information about the way that the string was produced. *Assuming* that it's originally UTF-8, the answer is a simple matter of decoding the string into a byte array, then recreating the string from a slice of that array.

Answer (score -1):

Do the valid data always starts with the same caracter? or the random caracters always ends with the same?

PS: sry for asking this here, i cant coment posts yet....

Comment: no... valid data keeps differing. both in length and content.